# Why my C# reflection code crashes?

Tags: c#

I'm just trying reflection :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;


public class CTest {
    public string test;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CTest cTest = new CTest();
        Type t=cTest.GetType();
        PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("test");
        cTest.test = "hello";
        //instruction below makes crash
        string test = (string)p.GetValue(cTest,null);

        Console.WriteLine(cTest.GetType().FullName);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: **ALWAYS** **ALWAYS** **ALWAYS** check values like `p` returned from a call like `GetProperty()` for `!= null` before accessing their properties and calling methods on them! **A-L-W-A-Y-S**

Comment: an unasked for bit of advice: rename the variable CTest to cTest, _cTest, M_cTest or whatever naming convention for local variables you fancy.
Now it is hard to determine whether a line like CTest.MyProp refers to a static property or an instance property. This is bound to cause hard to find bugs.

Comment: OK have renamed Ctest to ctest

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"`test`" is not a property, it's a field. You should use `Type.GetField` method to get a `FieldInfo`:

```
CTest CTest = new CTest();
Type t = CTest.GetType();
FieldInfo p = t.GetField("test");
CTest.test = "hello";
string test = (string)p.GetValue(CTest);

Console.WriteLine(CTest.GetType().FullName);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know about FieldInfo

Answer (score 8):

Others have observed that the member is a field. IMO, though, the best fix is to **make** it a property. Unless you're doing some very specific things, touching fields (from outside the class) is usually a bad idea:

```
public class CTest {
    public string test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I thought that by default making the variable public would like have get and set.

Comment: No; it if a public **field** unless you tell it to have a get/set.

Answer (score 4):

test is not a property, it is a member variable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;


public class CTest {
    public string test;
    public string test2 {get; set;}
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CTest CTest = new CTest();
        Type t=CTest.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldTest = t.GetField("test");
        CTest.test = "hello";
        string test = (string)fieldTest.GetValue(CTest);
        Console.WriteLine(test);


        PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("test2");
        CTest.test2 = "hello2";
        //instruction below makes crash
        string test2 = (string)p.GetValue(CTest,null);
        Console.WriteLine(test2);

        Console.ReadLine();     
    }
}
```